# Unable to get jenkins environments variable values in system groovy build step

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to execute a system groovy inside build.
I want to get the details of the following environment variables - 
BUILD_NUMBER
JOB_NAME
JOB_URL etc.
I used this code to fetch the values - 
String JName = System.getenv("%JOB_NAME"). Attached pic [Job Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMa1Q.jpg)
but this command is giving null value - 
JOB_NAME ::null. Attached pic [Job Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1rxL.jpg)
Please advise on this.

Comment: first of all, you don't need to specify percent ('%') sign in environment variable name

Comment: Might be related to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170 I would disable the security temporarily to check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying '%' sign, everything should work nicely at yours.
Here is a blunt test, run on Jenkins 2.24 + Groovy 1.29 plugin (Arch Linux host, but that doesn't matter):
[image]

And the output with environment variables available, as expected:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, but I tried this option, it is not working. I am still seeing null message.

Comment: I am using Jenkins 2.19.1 and Groovy plugin version - 1.29.

Comment: And I am using ***Execute System Groovy*** in build step to run these code and from your screenshot I see you are using ***Execute Groovy Script*** to run the code. So I am confused if this is causing the issue. Logically it shouldn't I guess, but I am not sure. Kindly advise on this.

Comment: With System Groovy script use `build.environment.JOB_NAME`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not able to fetch the environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its actually typo. I am ***able*** to fetch the environment variables with this command.

Comment: build.environment.JOB_NAME works for me in a system groovy script. Thanks a lot, Jenkins is too much complicated with access to environment variables / parameters depending on this or that !